# Camel Restlet -How to expose service using SSL

Tags: java, ssl, https, apache-camel, restlet

I'm exposing few REST services using the latest Apache Camel (2.14), more precisely using the Restlet Component (http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html).

Is there a way to expose the services under HTTPS ? I cannot find any documentation explaining how to set the SSL keystore, keystore password, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current camel-restlet doesn't support set the SSLContext information, I just fill a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7947) for it.

Comment: Hi @Willem Jiang, is it possible add the ssl support for the abbr url like from("restlet:/users/?restletMethods=post&sslContextParameters=#mySSLContextParameters") , or is there a convenient way to configure the host and port in the route dsl, not just hard code, thanks.

Comment: Since Camel 2.15.0, you can setup the sslContextParameters from URI just as you showed.