# How to specify host port in camel restlet route DSL?

Tags: apache-camel

I need to add the basic authentication for a camel web project, which I use the camel restlet component to expose the REST apis, from the camel documentation [Restlet Endpoint with Authentication](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html#Restlet-RestletEndpointwithAuthentication),

An approach is to use the "restletRealm" setting, I can pass the unit test actually, but encounter the problem when integrate it with the real application:

1. if I add the host/port in the route DSL, like `<from uri="restlet:http://localhost:8080/securedOrders?restletMethod=post&restletRealm=#realm"/>`
   this will cause the **Address already in use** error when tomcat startup
2. If I configure the route DSL like `<from uri="restlet:/securedOrders?restletMethod=post&restletRealm=#realm"/>`, this will blocking the route process.

Another approach is use the [SSL support after camel 2.15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503762/camel-restlet-how-to-expose-service-using-ssl), but still have the issue about add the host/port to the route DSL.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

**ENV:**

Camel:           2.15.2
Camel-Restlet:   2.15.2
Spring:          3.2.10.RELEASE

Comment: You cannot use port 8080 with restlet as that is used by Tomcat itself, use another port number.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Thanks, but is there a convenient way to specify the host and pot in the route dsl, not hard code with host and port.

Comment: You can use property placeholders - http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: @ClausIbsen Today I try to use another port number for the restlet, but get the 404 error  `org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException: Restlet operation failed invoking http://localhost:9527/securedOrders with statusCode: 404 /n responseBody:<html>`

Comment: BTW, I am follow the [Using the Restlet servlet within a webapp](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html)